# Dynamic length of an Excel chart

Tags: excel, variables, charts

How can I make a chart in excel to have variable length, depending on the data?

I will have a column where each row will be a day of the year (365 rows) and in each one will be written a percent. But the final calculation is like so: If the investment is <100, the chart to be as long as a 300 days, if the investment is >101 and <500, the chart include only 150 days, >500 - 90 days.

I made one, but it always including all 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with dynamic range names that grow and shrink based on the condition. Create a named range with a formula along the lines of

```
=IF(investment<101,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,if(investment<501,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$150,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$90))
```

Then use the range name in the chart series definition instead of a direct reference to worksheet cells.

Comment: Should I paste the formula in the data range? Because it says "The function is not valid"

Comment: It's the formula for a named range. You need to put it into the "Refers To" box of the Name Manager. You may need to read up on what named ranges are and how they work.